# How to perform nested ContextMenu implementation?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-6.0

I have this menu like this:

```
// open context menu
var contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
var versionsMenu = new ToolStripDropDownMenu() {Text = "Version"};
StaticHelpers.GetPackageVersions(textBlockSelected.Text).ForEach(f=> versionsMenu.Items.Add(f));
var scheduleMenu = new ToolStripMenuItem {Text = "Schedule"};
var argumentsMenu = new ToolStripMenuItem() {Text = "Arguments"};
var removeMenu = new ToolStripMenuItem {Text = "Remove"};

//show context menu
contextMenu.Items.Add(versionsMenu);
contextMenu.Items.Add(scheduleMenu);
contextMenu.Items.Add(argumentsMenu);
contextMenu.Items.Add(removeMenu);

//add handlers
// executeMenu.Click += (o, args) => { ExecutePackage(sender); };

//open context menu
contextMenu.IsOpen = true;
```

I have tried MenuItems instead of ToolStripMenuItem or ToolStripDropDownMenu but could not find any documentation or examples anywhere about how you can make these things nested, for example, when the user right clicks on one of my controls I want to show this menu:

- Version
- Schedule
- Arguments
- Remove

If the user hovers over version, I want another contextMenu to extend and show the following:

- V1.0
- V1.1
- V1.2

How can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: shouldn't it be as simple as `versionsMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem());`

Comment: @RandRandom https://gyazo.com/1abd6575931ddfdeca760f2de57b07f7 I tried that too, this is the output.

Comment: Not sure what you are doing wrong, but maybe this helps: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsgdY.png - as you can see no issue to be found, and everything  works as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a sub-menu, you take an existing item and do the same to it:

```
var versionsMenu = new ToolStripMenuItem();
versionsMenu.DropDownItems.Add(nestedItem);
```

Comment: This is the solution, thank you. I did not find anything related to DropDownItems and there seems to be some confusion being made online between ContextMenu class and ContextMenuStrip. Hopefully whoever googles how to do this finds this at the top.